# android - java.net.SocketException: Transport endpoint is not connected

Tags: android

What is the meaning of the following exception? when does it occur?.

Here is the exception log -

```
09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361): Unable to shutdown server socket

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361): java.net.SocketException: Transport endpoint is not connected

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.shutdownInputImpl(Native Method)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.shutdownInput(OSNetworkSystem.java:637)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.shutdownInput(PlainSocketImpl.java:442)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.net.Socket.shutdownInput(Socket.java:819)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.restlet.engine.http.StreamServerCall.complete(StreamServerCall.java:108)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerAdapter.commit(HttpServerAdapter.java:477)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.restlet.engine.http.HttpServerHelper.handle(HttpServerHelper.java:150)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at org.restlet.engine.http.StreamServerHelper$ConnectionHandler.run(StreamServerHelper.java:90)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)

09-22 12:19:08.329: WARN/LogFilter(8361):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
```

thanks

Comment: What did you do? When did it happen?

Comment: i am downloading the images from the web

Comment: I have this error when i tryed to download a Xml from a URL that is not reachable because the  url is in localhost and the movile was not connected to the same network

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are missing the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```